# Can you emit events in a contract constructor?

Tags: events, constructor

I have a constructor that is emitting an event, but cannot seem to see/catch/filter that event after deployment.

Comment: How are you catching/filtering events?

Comment: I have tried filtering via `ethers.js` from block 0-latest with no luck, although future events come through just fine. I also tried using the Ganache GUI. Starting from a fresh state I deploy the contracts and everything looks fine except the expected events are not shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes you can**.

I put the answer in plain and simple language, in case future people find this question. But your problem is most likely related to how you're filtering events.

Comment: The problem was related to event filtering. I was able to see the events come through using `web3.eth.getPastLogs({fromBlock: deployedBlockNumber, toBlock: deployedBlockNumber})`. Going to try and figure out why ethers.js route was not working and post back.

Comment: @NeilHarlow were you able to resolve this somehow?